# Date out of range pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to retrive date from mongodb but it's out of the range date in python.

I tried setting the min and max but the problel still occurs. Can anyone help please ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am filtering data of whole one day, hope this will work

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pymongo
client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb", 27017)
db = client["attendance"]
daily = db.daily
fy,fm,fd=request.json["from_date"].split("-")
fy,fm,fd=int(fy),int(fm),int(fd)
ty,tm,td=request.json["to_date"].split("-")
ty,tm,td=int(ty),int(tm),int(td)
start_date = datetime(fy,fm,fd,hour=0,minute=0,second=0)
end_date = datetime(ty,tm,td-1,hour=23,minute=59,second=59) + timedelta(1)
result=daily.find({'Date':{"$gte":start_date, "$lte":start_date + timedelta(1)}})
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. Can you please explain from_date and to_date? Am i supposed to replace them by something?

Comment: Sorry for late response. I am taking these from API post request where user can provide From DATE and To DATE , eg 2022-12-06 to 2022-12-09.